# Does it help with page SEO if I have a google map on the page?

Tags: seo, google-ranking, google-maps

I know having images or video sometimes helps boost a page's SEO.  But what about a google map of some relevant things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

I'm responsible for a site that has one of the largest implementations of Google Maps (per impressions) outside of Google Maps itself (in Australia). Both with that, and with overlay (including links) of data, we have seen on 1million+ pages that with or without Google Maps has zero effect on the page's ranking.

I'm not going to speculate on the specifics of *why* this doesn't impact SEO (because I simply don't know definitively), but most of Google Maps requires the execution of JavaScript, and as we know, while Google does indeed crawl and execute some JS, it's mostly for link discovery and detection of spammy redirects.

Answer (score 5):

It will boost the SEO if it makes it more useful for people (not search engines), and they link to it. Not directly though.

Comment: Isn't that the case for everything? :)

Comment: Yes, but not many people are asking here "how can I optimise my site for people".